# MinEnclosingCircle is not stable when object fast motion opencv android

Tags: opencv

I have a project with opencv in android, i try to detect ball and i decide use MinEnclosingCircle, But i have problem when i move object so fast. I cannot get exactly radius of ball. Because of this phenomenon.

When object stand by, I get image like below:

[image]

But when i move ball from right to left, left to right so fast i get wrong radius because of this phenomenon

[image]

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem. So many thank for your help.

**EDIT 1**: More detail about image that i get

This is image not draw circle that i captured
[image]

And this is image which show contour of ball 
[image]

It quite a dim, so i draw contour to see easier.

[image]

Comment: what's the expected result? I would start computing the center of gravity and the mean/median distance of the contour to the cog. If you want one of the borders instead (which each form about 1/3 circle) I would try houghCircle or RANSAC circle detection on the contour to detect semi circles.

Comment: ok... right radius (with unknown correct position?) I would compute the CoG and compute the minimum distance to the outer contour.

Comment: The result that i would like is a exactly radius, i was use Hough circle, i can not get stable radius with this method, i was use findhomography too, but it too slow, and it not suitle for my realtime application. With findcontour and minenclosingCircle, i get stable center position and radius, but it can't detect exactly radius when ball move left to right, right to left too fast, so do you have any idea to solve it :(

Comment: please try to compute the center of gravity and the minimum distance to the border.

Comment: can you add the mask images without drawn circles?

Comment: ok, wait me just a minute, i will capture it and show for you

Comment: maybe I can just mask the red color out...

Comment: Hello Micka, are you there, i have uploaded image in edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works quite well I guess:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/ballMaskClean2.png");
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/ballMaskClean1.png");



    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::cvtColor(input, mask, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    //cv::inRange(input, cv::Scalar(200, 200, 200), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), mask); // was used for your provided images with red circle inside
    cv::imshow("mask", mask);


    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    cv::Mat cleanMask = cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), CV_8UC1);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::drawContours(cleanMask, contours, i, 255, -1); // draw filled
    }
    //cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Input/ballMaskClean.png", cleanMask);


    cv::Mat dt;
    cv::distanceTransform(cleanMask, dt, CV_DIST_L1, 3);

    double minVal, maxVal;
    cv::Point minLoc, maxLoc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(dt, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);

    double radius = maxVal;
    cv::Point2f center = maxLoc;
    cv::circle(input, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

    cv::imshow("output", input);
    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Input/ballCircle.png", input);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

using these input I get that output:
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello Micka, sorry about respond late, i solved my problem by the way use morphology to do that, Result was quite good, But i will still use your way to learn more. Just one thing i don't understand and i would like ask that: what to do distanceTransform and minmaxLoc, i know distancetransform, but i don't know what your purpose when you use distancetransform and minmaxLoc

Comment: want to find the interior of the roi which has the furthest distance to the border

Comment: Oh i am understand now, finally i would like to thank you so much about your help :D